# Silverlight Video File Won't Play; Can see .ism/manifest

Tags: silverlight, iis, streaming, smoothing

I am running Windows Server 2008 SP2. I have an IIS 7.0 Webserver installed running IIS Media Services Beta 1. I also have WebDAV 7.5 installed.

I encoded a video file, MP4(H.264/AAC), to the smooth streaming protocol using Expression Encoder 4.0 Pro. Under "Default Web Site" I added a virtual directory to the encoded video and created a simple page with an embedded Silverlight player to view the content.

Simply put the page loads up, and never starts playing. If I go the the .ism file in a browser I can see it fine as an .xml.

I loaded up the default content that microsoft privides from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e44b0a2d-2e0c-48ff-bf57-3d05a20e2f6a&displayLang=en

If I try to play that file in the webpage it DOES work.

### Here is my Question:

Why does the sample content work, but mine doesn't? Do I need to add some permissions somewhere so my file can be accessed? Was my file encoded incorrectly?

My File: http://128.113.16.8/library/kissxsis/1/1.ism/manifest

Sample File: http://128.113.16.8/library/bbb/Big%20Buck%20Bunny.ism/manifest

*Edit1: Embed code for the player I am using to play the .ism*

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="source" value="SmoothStreamingBlackGlass.xap"/>
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0"/>
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true"/>
<param name="InitParams" value="mediaurl= http://128.113.16.8/library/kissxsis/1/1.ism/Manifest"/>
</object>
```

Comment: Did you follow the Deployment Guide at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/689/smooth-streaming-deployment-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight's MediaElement can't play an ism directly - you need to use a smooth streaming player in a Silverlight app.

Which player are you using?
Are you using the Silverlight Media Framework Player or the Smooth Streaming Media Element?

Did you follow the [deployment guide](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/689/smooth-streaming-deployment-guide/)?